# Why is & turning into &amp; after page load?

Tags: html, knockout.js, special-characters

I'm using Firefox and working on a page when I notice that `&` turns into `&amp;`.

Usually I can fix this by using `html_entitiy_decode()` - but in this case it's not working.

Then I discovered this. The alert is fired once the page is loaded.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

The data is loaded using PHP / Yii - not through JS / Ajax. I am however adding / removing brands using JS Knockout.

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'brand-item-template', data: $root.brands}">
  <li>
    <span id="<?= $brand->id?>" data-bind="text: brand_name, attr: {'id': brand_id}"><?= $brand->name; ?></span>
    <a href="#" class="remove el-icon-remove-circle" data-bind="click: $parent.removeBrand"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Update**

I've discovered that this `JS Knockout` code is what makes the change. But this code should not be triggered until I add a brand. So why is this affecting my `&`s?

It's the `self.addBrand = function()` that makes the change. If I remove this function and leave the rest as it is, everything is fine. **Can it be a Knockout bug?**

```
$('#store.manage-special-offers').exists(function(){
    Store.mangeSpecialOffers();
});

function manageBrandListModel() {
    var self = this;
    var store_id = $('.data-item-id').val();
    var exiting_list = $('.brand-list ul').clone();

    // Data
    self.brands = ko.observableArray(create_list(exiting_list));
    self.brand_name = ko.observable();
    self.brand_id = ko.observable();
    self.store_id = ko.observable(store_id);

    // This is the function that makes the chage
    self.addBrand = function() {

        if (self.brand_name() != "") {

            // Update DB
            $('#store.manage-brands').exists(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: site_url + '/associatebrand',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        Brand: {
                           brandId : self.brand_id(),
                           storeId : self.store_id(),
                           add : true
                       }
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        // Add brand to GUI list
                        self.brands.push(new brand(self.brand_id(), self.brand_name()));
                        self.brand_name("");
                    }
                });
            });


        }
    }.bind(self);

    (...)


function create_list(exiting_list){
    var arr_list = [];

    $(exiting_list).find('li').each(function(e,li){
        var id = $(li).find('span').prop('id');
        var name = $(li).find('span').html(); // <--- This is the problem. Must be .text()
        arr_list.push(new brand(id,name));
     });
    return arr_list;
}
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: What's happening in your code? Can you post some JavaScript? If you're using `html_entity_decode()`, it sounds like you're making a XHR call to a PHP backend?

Comment: Thanks, Updated code. The data is loaded from PHP. I'm not using XHR call until I add / delete a brand.

Comment: I can't. My users will add their brand name using `&`

Comment: Can you use something like Firebug to see what's being returned from the server when JS Knockout makes a request?

Comment: I've maanged to narrow it down to the code bit shown above. It's indeed JS that makes the change (JS Knockout). But I have no idea why.

Comment: Presumably, you have a function which takes text and puts it into the DOM, and then another function which takes HTML out of the DOM and does something with it. You should change the latter function so it gets text instead of HTML.

Comment: How do they add the brands in the first place? Could you perform some kind of str_replace on the input field that converts & to &amp;?

Comment: @Quentin, I think Knockout does this with `data-bind="text: brand_name`. I have no controll if it justtakes the text or HTML (I think)

Comment: Please add the code of the `create_list(exiting_list)` function.

Comment: @JeremyCook Quentin was right and you pointed me to where :) In this function I was using `.html()` when I should have used `.text()`. You may add an answer if you like :)

Comment: `Can it be a Knockout bug?` You're obviously passing in `&amp;` to knockout: http://jsfiddle.net/yqpr1dz8/1/

Comment: @Steven if you manage to answer a question yourself you can either delete it or post and accept an answer yourself, otherwise it will remain "unanswered" forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credit should really go to both JeremyCook and Quentin for pointing me in the right direction.

```
 $(exiting_list).find('li').each(function(e,li){
    var id = $(li).find('span').prop('id');
    var name = $(li).find('span').html(); // <--- This is the problem. Must be .text()
    arr_list.push(new brand(id,name));
 });
```

What I did wrong was that I used `.html()` and the text was returned in HTML format. Changing this to `.text()` solved my problem.